# iptables INPUT prevents outgoing mail and ping

Tags: iptables

My standard policy on `INPUT` is set to `DROP`.

However, due to this setting I'm not able to connect to an external mailing host. What rule would I need to enable connecting to this external host.

Note that `ping` also doesn't work, though this is merely for testing purposes (it doesn't need to work, but may help in finding the root issue).\

**Edit**

```
[root@webshop ~]# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 150 packets, 18963 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 378K  178M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       xxxxxxxxxxxxx        0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:56988 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 4 name: DEFAULT side: source
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:56988
  628 42832 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 8080,8181
 7682  765K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           multiport dports 8080,8181

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 933 packets, 616K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: Show the output of iptables -L -v -n

Comment: @ALex_hha Done. `xxxxxxxxxxxx` represents my home IP which enables me to make use of `JMX` et cetera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Communication goes in two directions, you send queries to another host (via OUTPUT) and the other host responds (to INPUT). Your current rules cause all responses to get dropped. Try the adding the following rule in order to accept those responses:

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Without this rule, TCP ACK packets, ICMP echo-reply, etc. get dropped because you have no rule allowing them.

Comment: I personally recommend against including `,RELATED` merely on a cargo-cult basis.  It's not needed in order to solve this particular problem, and including it can open your firewall to all sorts of odd traffic depending on which kernel modules are loaded.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks for the addition, I'll close whatever doesn't need to be open :)